# Changing Ehcache cache size via jmx

Tags: java, spring, jmx, ehcache-2

I've added Ehcache jmx monitoring using this article https://khushroomistry.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/monitoring-ehcache-spring/

What I failed to figure out is how could I enable cache size adjustment via jmx? Is it possible at all?

Found pure java way in docs http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.4/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-cfgbasics_dynamically_changing_cache_config.html%23

But no standard out-of-the-box way :(

(Ehcache 2.10)

Thanks in advance!